What does the betweenness centrality value of a vertex generated by Mathematica actually mean?
Suppose I have a vertex A in a directed graph. Suppose Mathematica computes its betweenness centrality is 29000.3. What does 29000.3 actually represent? Does it mean 29000.3 times vertex A is on all pairs shortest (s,t) paths in my network? Is it actually a count? What is the best way to explain it to a layman? This is the non-normalized value. The same question for edge betweenness centrality Mathematica generates. Suppose I have an edge C->D and Mathematica generates an edge betweenness of 4956.2. Does it mean the edge C->D is traversed 4956.2 times on all pairs shortest (s,t) paths in my network?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Wolfram Mathematica but about a meaning of a mathematical quantity. You can find the definition in the documentation for BetweennessCentrality, you can read more about it on Wikipedia or ask on Math.SE.

There is a defining formula in the documentation.

The documentation is poor

It's mathematically correct in the documentation. I'm trying to explain the number  generated by Wolfram Mathematica to a non-tech audience

Basically, does the betweenness value actually represent a count of the number of times vertex A is on all pairs shortest (s,t) paths in my network?

I've asked this question to Wolfram's Tech Support and they were unable to explain what the number generated means.

I can't fathom why this question has so many close votes.  Yes there is a formula in the doc page, but I think "what does this number mean?" is still a fair question and definitely on topic for this site.

Let us take the simplest example from documentation:
g = Graph[{UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[1, 3], 
    UndirectedEdge[3, 6], UndirectedEdge[4, 6], UndirectedEdge[5, 1], 
    UndirectedEdge[5, 4], UndirectedEdge[6, 1]}];


The MA function returns
BetweennessCentrality[g]
(*{5.5, 0., 0., 2., 0.5, 1.}*)

This can be re-implemented as
BtwCnt[g_] := Module[{m, n, s, t, subg, nv, lst, sublst}, Table[
   subg = DeleteCases[VertexList[g], i];
   nv = VertexCount[g];
   Table[s = subg[[m]];
      t = subg[[n]];
      lst = FindPath[g, s, t, {GraphDistance[g, s, t]}, All];
      sublst = Cases[lst, {___, i, ___}];
      Length[sublst]/Length[lst],
      {m, nv - 1},
      {n, m + 1, nv - 1}] // Flatten // Total
   , {i, VertexList[g]}]]

and verified that results are as expected:
BtwCnt[g]
(*{11/2, 0, 0, 2, 1/2, 1}*)

Here lst is the list of all shortest paths from s to t, and sublst is the list of all shortest paths from s to t that go through the i-th vertex.
The algorithms works as follows.

For a given vertex number i prepare a sub-list (subg) of vertices that does not contain the ith vertex.
Iterate over distinct vertex pairs (s, t) from subg, where s should not be equal to t.
Find all shortest paths from s to t and put them in lst.
Select from lst only those paths that go through the ith vertex and put them into sublst.
Compute the fraction Length[sublst]/Length[lst].
Finally, sum fractions over all pairs.


so, 5.5 is a count of the number of times vertex 1 on all (s,t) shortest paths.

@user42700  count is something that can only be integer: 1, 2, 3,. Count cannot be fractional. In fact, 5.5 is a sum of quotients Length[sublst]/Length[lst] for each (s, t) pair
